# Create new columns from splitting string column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I'm looking to do is create new columns that capture each word in a string. Example is here:

df

```
Col1        Col2  
 38       'My Name is John'
 11       'Hello friend'
 134      'My favorite city is New Orleans'
```

desired df:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7
38      'My'   'Name'    'is'   'John'   NA      NA
11     'Hello' 'friend'   NA     NA      NA      NA
134     'My'  'favorite' 'city' 'is'    'New' 'Orleans'
```

Does anybody have any ideas for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `str.split` will split the strings in the columns in a list of words. Then you can fill the lists so that they all have the same length and create a new dataframe out of this:

```py
words = df.text.str.split()
maxlen = words.map(len).max()

def pad_list(l):
    return l + [None] * (maxlen - len(l))

words = pd.DataFrame(np.stack(words.map(pad_list), axis=0))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create it using this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [38, 11, 134], 
                    'Col2':['My Name is John', 'Hello friend', 'My favorite city is New Orleans']})
 

df1 = df.Col2.str.split(expand=True) 

df1.columns = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `Col2` into a series that contains a list with the words and then convert the series back into a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

# OPs data
x = ['My Name is John', 'Hello friend', 'My favorite city is New Orleans']
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['Col2'])

# convert to series with lists
s = df['Col2'].apply(lambda x: x.split())

# lists to dataframe
df_new = pd.DataFrame(item for item in s)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should do. It does not use pandas dataframes but it calls the colums by their keys and stores them in their keys, again. So, it should be completely compatible with pandas.

```
def splitcolumn(data,colname):
    ncol = 0
    for s in data[colname]:
        n = len(s.split(' '))
        if n>ncol:ncol=n   
    addcol = {}
    for i in range(ncol):
        addcol["{0}_{1}".format(colname,i)] = []
    for s in data[colname]:
        elements = s.split(' ')
        for i in range(ncol):
            try:
                addcol["{0}_{1}".format(colname,i)].append(elements[i])
            except:
                addcol["{0}_{1}".format(colname,i)].append(None)
    for a in addcol.keys():
        data[a] = addcol[a]
    return data
                
data = {'Col2': ['My Name is John','Hello friend','My favorite city is New Orleans']}

data = splitcolumn(data,'Col2')
```

Other than in your example, the column `Col2` is not overwritten or removed, instead the new columns are added to the end of the data as `Col2_0`, `Col2_1`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import pandas as pd

split_ = df.Col2.str.split(expand=True)
split_.columns = [f"Col{x}" for x in range(2, split_.columns.size + 2)]

print(
    pd.concat([df.Col1, split_], axis=1)
)
```

---

```
   Col1   Col2      Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6     Col7
0    38     My      Name    is  John  None     None
1    11  Hello    friend  None  None  None     None
2   134     My  favorite  city    is   New  Orleans
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [[38, 'My Name is John'], [11, 'Hello friend'], [114, 'My favorite city is New Orleans']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df.join(df[1].str.split(' ', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C'}))
df1.drop([1], axis = 1, inplace = True) 
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
     0      A         B     C     3     4        5
0   38     My      Name    is  John  None     None
1   11  Hello    friend  None  None  None     None
2  114     My  favorite  city    is   New  Orleans
```